# Calling System.out.println() through a lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

In C# I can write the following code:

```
public static Action<object> WL = x => Console.WriteLine(x);
```

... and then every time that I want to write something out to the console I just call:

```
WL("Some output");
```

What would be the equivalent code using Java 8 lambda expressions? I tried the following and it does not work:

```
static void WL = (String s) -> { System.out.println(s); }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your current attempt doesn't work because you're trying to declare a variable of type `void` - the equivalent would fail in C# too. You need to declare a variable of a suitable *functional interface*, just like you use a delegate type in C#.

You can do it with a lambda expression, but it would be cleaner (IMO) to use a method reference:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<Object> c1 = x -> System.out.println(x);
        Consumer<Object> c2 = System.out::println;

        c1.accept("Print via lambda");
        c2.accept("Print via method reference");
    }
}
```

Here the [`Consumer<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) interface is broadly equivalent to the `Action<T>` delegate in .NET.

Similarly you can use a method group conversion in C# rather than a lambda expression:

```
public static Action<object> WL = Console.WriteLine;
```

Comment: I think I like the method reference strategy better also. Thanks!

Comment: Note that there’s a small semantic difference. The method reference is unchangeably bound to the value of `System.out` found at the time when the `Consumer` was created while the lambda will execute the statement as usual when `accept` is invoked, reading `System.out` right before calling `println`. Of course, this makes a difference when `System.out` [is changed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-) only.

Comment: @Holger: yes, I thought of pointing that out in the answer, but decided to leave it.

Answer (score 1):

```
interface MyMethod {
    public void print(String s);
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyMethod method = (String s) -> { };
    }
}
```

In java, lambda expressions revolve around functional interfaces; interfaces only containing one method.

Comment: You can also use the java.util.function.Consumer interface.

Comment: There's no need to declare your own interface though - `Consumer<T>` works perfectly well for this.